# How does this HTML5 game read its localstorage data?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to write a cheat for a game called [Idle Breakout](https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-idle-breakout/play), and I can't figure out how they read and write to their localstorage save file. I at first thought it was something to do with JSON, but when I tried something like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("breakout.924370207.save.dat"))` it returned nothing. If you want to take a glance at the code (its obfuscated so good luck understanding it) [here's the link.](https://www.coolmathgames.com//sites/cmatgame/files/public_games/26455/html5game/Coding_BreakOut1.js?WJJAC=1368545285)

They format their saves like this in localstorage:

```
[main]
level="1"
money="50"
gold="0"
[bt]
0="57"
```

I can't understand how they do stuff like for example: change money to 51 or add 1 to level.

How could I be able to change specific values like money or gold?

Comment: The syntax looks like an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). There are several libraries that can read/write INI-formatted data; the `npm` package [`ini`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini) springs to mind. The question as you've written it is not a great fit for Stack Overflow. Please edit to show what you've researched and tried so far, why it's not working, and to limit your question to a distinct, answerable inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

normally if you want to set localstorage variable with JS , you can use :

```
localStorage.setItem('nameOfVariable', value);
```

Maybe in your case , they use this way to store new values to localStorage.

If you want to get variable from localStorage you can use :

```
localStorage.getItem('nameOfVariable');
```

You can store it to local variable , something like that :

```
var localMoney = localStorage.getItem('money');

// Do something with local variable : 

localMoney = 55;

localStorage.setItem('money', localMoney );
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, all of the variables are stored in a single localstorage file, not in separate ones.

Comment: Hmm , for me this look like , 'breakout.924370207.save.dat' is the Key , ant all other info is Array , let me show you img  : https://pasteboard.co/IGGt8yf.png 
I think , they use the same way .

And from here they set values of different keys in Array .